# Can I replace the eccentric bottom bracket in my Salsa El Mariachi with standard BB?

Tags: bottom-bracket

I have an older [Salsa El Mariachi](http://salsacycles.com/bikes/archive/el_mariachi1) with a [Bushnell eccentric bottom bracket](http://www.bushnelltandems.com/eccentric.html) with 54mm O.D.

Do I have any options to replace the EBB with a non-eccentric bottom bracket?

The current bottom bracket has threaded openings to accept a standard 68mm English thread BB, currently running a standard GXP bottom bracket and crankset in the Bushnell EBB.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The that my cranks are not centered in the bottom bracket, and the EBB keeps coming loose, I stripped one of the bolts on the EBB since all my allen wrenches are ball ended, and I'll probably kill the existing English threaded bottom bracket anyway in the next 6 months because I don't disassemble my bike for rigorous cleaning often enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen something like that, an eccentric to concentric conversion BB. Even if it existed it would have all the issues of an eccentric, so the only benefit would be if you really wanted that otherwise unattainable chainstay length. If you really, really wanted this, just having one made would be pretty easy. If you're having creak troubles you could try a Niner eccentric, which has been known to solve the problem.